# How to migrate a multi-instance LSB script to systemd?

Tags: systemd, init-script, lsb

I wrote an LSB init script that can manage multiple instances of my daemon:
`rcfoo start` starts all the instances (which are found in some `/etc` configuration file), `rcfoo stop` stops all the instances, `rcfoo status` displays the status of all instances, and `rcfoo reload` reloads updates the daemon with a changed configuration.

First I wonder how to detect the instances to work on with some `foo@.service` systemd unit file. AFAIK I must specify all the instances like `foo@A`, `foo@B`, and so on.

Second my LSB script can report an extended status, meaning it can display whether a service `reload` is needed (and my `reload` actually optimizes to only reload the services that need it). How can I make a custom status report? I think a script has to use `systemd-notify` for custom status messages.

Fortunately my final extension to the LSB script, namely manipulating single instances by adding `single <instance>` (like in `rcfoo start single A`), is supported out-of-the-box with systemd.

So my basic question is the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two possible solutions:

1. Write a "wrapper script" that accepts an instance parameter and a command parameter.  Then the script has to search whether the instance requested is actually found in the configuration file in `/etc`. The script actually does provide `start`, `stop`, and `reload`, while the PID of the daemon process is handled by systemd via `PIDFile=`.

   In addition write a service unit like `foo@.service` that contains the wrapper script for `ExecStart=`, `ExecStop=`, etc.  The instance name is represented by `%i` there.    What's not so nice is the fact that you'll have to know the instance names, and when using an invalid one, systemd creates a non-operational instance that is repeatedly restarting (until cleaned up manually with `systemctl reset-failed`).  The thing with conditional restart wasn't solved with this approach.  So you would `systemctl start foo@A`.
2. Alternatively you can get rid of the wrapper script by writing a generator reads the configuration file and creates a service instance unit file for each instance found.  The command-lines being used is assembled by the generator using the config file.  Additional shell commands (e.g. to create a runtime-directory, or to wait for daemon fork to complete) are added by the generator via `ExecStartPre=` and `ExecStartPost=`.

   There are some issues unresolved, but the systemd community represented on the development list wasn't actually helpful: They told me generators are an advanced concept that *I should not use it*, not actually answering my questions.

Things missing in this answer are: How to configure a sytemd target that starts and stops all services?  I thought I'd have one, but it failed on boot (generated unit file was empty for unknown reasons).